# How to check if a specific array element contains a specific word?

Tags: swift

This function aims to take an array of strings and sort them into two separate arrays—one with elements that contain the word "gold" and one with elements that do not.

The error I get is on line 7 "if i.contains("gold") {". What is the proper way to execute this?

```
func findgold(_ list: [String]) -> (gold: [String], nogold: [String]) {

    var gold = [String]()
    var nogold = [String]()

    for i in list {
        if i.contains("gold") {
            gold.append(i)
        } else {
            nogold.append(i)
        }
    }

    return (gold, nogold)

}

print(findgold(["golden glove", "mold", "ladder", "gold nugget", "taco"]))
```

Comment: Just tried this in the playground and works just fine. What is the error?

Comment: Did you import Foundation or UIKit in your file?

Comment: the error was "value of type 'String' has no member 'contains'" but I just missed an import file, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

`contains` method was introduced in Swift 3.
Here is solution for Swift 2:

Replace

```
if i.contains("gold") {
```

With

```
if i.rangeOfString("gold") != nil {
```